# Textfield in the not showing keyboard platform android in native script angular

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

when i am writing in text field then that text field getting hidden behind the keyboard. 
i have also tried below code add in Androidmanifest.xml
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden | adjustPan"

Comment: You should wrap your layout with a ScrollView, so it can scroll and adjust the screen to focus the TextField properly on Android. For iOS you may have to install [nativescript-IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/tjvantoll/nativescript-IQKeyboardManager) plugin. If you still have issues, please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

adjustResize is more [preferable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) in your case.

> "**adjustResize**"    The activity's main window is always resized to make
>   room for the soft keyboard on screen.
>
> "**adjustPan**"   The activity's main window is not resized to make room for
>   the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are
>   automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by
>   the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is
>   generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to
>   close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of
>   the window.